# Heroku/Celery: Simultaneous tasks on one worker?

Tags: django, heroku, celery

Is it possible to use Celery to set up multiple updating tasks to run simultaneously on Django/Heroku on just ONE worker? If I schedule certain functions to run every 5 minutes, will they automatically overlap in terms of when they start running, or will they wait till all other tasks are finished? I'm new to Celery and frankly vary confused over what it can do? ):

Answer (score 4):

By default Celery uses multiprocessing to perform concurrent execution of tasks. Celery worker launches a pool of processes to consume tasks. The number of processes in a pool is set by *--concurrency* argument and defaults to the number of CPUs available on the machine.

So if the concurrency level is greater than one then the tasks will be processed in parallel.

Comment: So essentially, specifying overlapping times (10 tasks every 15 minutes) in celery beat is ok, and tasks will automatically queue up if more than the concurrency argument is attempted at once?

Comment: celerybeat periodically publishes tasks. Tasks can be processed in parallel even they are not published at the same time.